# Как удалить запись из бинарного файла по определённому условию

Tags: c++, файлы, структуры

Есть структура:

```
struct student
{
    char name[50], gr[8], birth[11];
    int num, hist, math, prog; char skip[4];
};
```

Я пытался, ничего не вышло (попробовал создать новый файл и его потом переименовать в старый), совсем запутался :

```
void del_skip(const char* name)
{
    student z;
    FILE* f; FILE* temp;
    const char* t = "temp.txt";
    int k = number_of_records1(name);
    f = fopen(name, "rb");
    student* b = new student[k];
    while (fread(&z, sizeof(student), 1, f))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < k; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(z.skip, "NO")==0) b[i] = z;
        }
    }
    temp = fopen(t, "wb"); 
    int k1 = sizeof(b) / sizeof(b[0]);
    for (int i = 0; i <= k1; i++)
    {

        fwrite(&b, sizeof(student), 1, temp);
    }

    fclose(f);
    remove(name);
    //f = fopen(name, "wb"); fclose(f);
    //while (fread(&b,sizeof(student),1,temp))
    //{
    //  fwrite(&b, sizeof(student), 1, f);
    //}
    rename(t, name);
    fclose(temp); 
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(b)` - с динамическим массивом такой фокус не пройдет. Используйте переменную, которая отвечает за размер массива (`k`)